# Wrong title bar icon size in Adobe Air on Windows

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, windows-7, air, adobe

I am facing a really annoying problem. I am supplying both 16x16 and 32x32 application icons yet the initial window is using the 32x32 icon, scaled down, instead of the 16x16 icon.

Here are the respective icon images:

[image]

[image]

So it would make sense to use the 16x16 icon for the application icon, Windows or whatever doesn't seem to think so:

[image]

How do I fix this? It's really annoying and looks incredibly unprofessional when every other use of the application icons are clear and crisp except the damn window icon.

This error/bug also occurs in the taskbar.

[image]

Any ideas?

**Edit:** application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.5">
  <id>com.yahrly.PixelTBSLevelEditor</id>
  <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
  <filename>PixelTBS Level Editor</filename>
  <name>PixelTBS Level Editor</name>
  <copyright>© 2013, YahRly LLC</copyright>
  <initialWindow>
    <title>PixelTBS Level Editor</title>
    <content>PixelTBSLevelEditor.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <minimizable>true</minimizable>
    <maximizable>false</maximizable>
    <resizable>false</resizable>
  </initialWindow>
  <installFolder>YahRly</installFolder>
  <programMenuFolder>PixelTBS Level Editor</programMenuFolder>
  <supportedProfiles>desktop</supportedProfiles>
  <icon>
    <image16x16>icons/icon16.png</image16x16>
    <image32x32>icons/icon32.png</image32x32>
    <image48x48>icons/icon48.png</image48x48>
    <image128x128>icons/icon128.png</image128x128>
  </icon>
  <description>Create and customise your own maps for PixelTBS.</description>
</application>
```

**Edit 2:** I found someone else with my problem but they've had no response either >> [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3926988)

Comment: can you post your descriptor .xml file?

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 updated the original post

Comment: I had a similar issue with icons. I think it's a bug in AIR.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try:

1. Make sure the correct icon files are being packaged. Sometimes it's easy to forget that previous icons are still being used if they are still available in the `bin` folder (for example) of your project, which ADT might still be calling.
2. Check your icons to see if they are indeed the correct versions.
3. Clean your project, recompile and then repackage.
4. Use all available icon sizes in your descriptor file:

**application.xml**

```
<icon>
    <image512x512>icons/OffAirIcon512.png</image512x512>
    <image128x128>icons/OffAirIcon128.png</image128x128>
    <image72x72>icons/OffAirIcon72.png</image72x72>
    <image57x57>icons/OffAirIcon57.png</image57x57>
    <image48x48>icons/OffAirIcon48.png</image48x48>
    <image36x36>icons/OffAirIcon36.png</image36x36>
    <image32x32>icons/OffAirIcon32.png</image32x32>
    <image29x29>icons/OffAirIcon29.png</image29x29>
    <image16x16>icons/OffAirIcon16.png</image16x16>
</icon>
```

I suspect the problem is #1, but If none of this works please reply with details on how you are your packaging your application?  What is your ADT command?  Are you using FlashDevelop?  Flash Builder?

---

**[EDIT]**

It seems that unique Taskbar and System Trey icons need to be loaded programmatically and an array of the [*flash.desktop.InteractiveIcon.bitmaps*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/InteractiveIcon.html#bitmaps) assigned to [*flash.desktop.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#icon).bitmaps, as indicated here:

[**Taskbar icons in AIR**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a4af7-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dcc)

I realize that while this doesn't answer your question, it should certainly work.  It does raise questions about the 16 x 16 pixel sized icon file not being used as one would expect (for the Taskbar / System Trey), but perhaps the `application.xml` icons are specifically for viewing in Windows Explorer.  If you mouse over your Desktop and press Ctrl while scrolling your mouse, you will see that Windows Explorer is also capable of displaying 16 x 16 pixel sized icons.

Comment: It's the correct icons, I originally had an icon for every single size but I thought it was using, say, 29x29 instead of 16x16 so figured I'd remove those ones and just have the 4 main ones. If I open Explorer and resize the icon to extremely small then yes, it does use the 16x16 icon. However, for the taskbar and title bar the icon size is plain wrong. I'm not sure if it always goes with the next size up or what but I just feel that if it used the 16x16 icon then it would look clear and crisp like I want. The icons are definitely the correct size and file format, no errors returned.

Comment: (the images attached to my original post proves this as they are the exact same image files). I am also using FlashDevelop if that makes any difference. I also tried cleaning the project, recompiling and repackaging. Still uses the 32x32 scaled down.

Comment: I use the auto-generated FlashDevelop AIR batch files (PackageApp.bat etc).

Comment: Is your `icons` folder containing the correct icon files inside the `bin` folder of your project?

Comment: I am not using a system tray icon at all and everything else about that URL you posted concerns Mac OSX. The title bar icon is being resampled using the 32x32 icon instead of just using the 16x16 icon at its original size. It's starting to seem more and more that this is a bug and there's no way of actually fixing this which is a shame.

Comment: Ah, you're correct, sorry about that.  I should have read it more thoroughly before posting - although I did learn about Windows Taskbar icon notifications thru that article which I wasn't aware of.

Comment: I've searched the Adobe AIR bugs database and there isn't anything posted about this issue.  I would suggest that you submit a bug here:  https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform